# Refactor view code to decorator using .each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I'm just learning how to move view code into decorators using the draper gem. I'm having trouble figuring out how to move .each into the decorator.

```
<% @project.users.each do |p| %>
    <small class="btn btn-mini">
        <%= link_to "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", "mailto:#{p.email}" %>
    </small>
    <br>
<% end %>
```

I tried the following:

View code:

```
<%= @project.assigned_users %>
```

Decorator code:

```
def assigned_users
    model.users.each do |p|
        h.content_tag :small, class: 'btn btn-mini' do
            h.link_to "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", "mailto:#{p.email}"
        end
    end
end
```

The result is the entire user hash instead of the first_name last_name button I'm looking for. Maybe .each doesn't belong in the decorator? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` returns the original hash. You need instead to caoncatenate the result of your block:

```
def assigned_users
    model.users.map do |p|
        h.content_tag :small, class: 'btn btn-mini' do
            h.link_to "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", "mailto:#{p.email}"
        end
    end.flatten.join.html_safe
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. NOTE: I had to add `.html_safe` on the end line (end.flatten.join.html_safe) so it would display correctly.